# iOS9 Email Push Still Not Working

Tags: ios, email, notifications

There seems to be a general iphone issue with mail.app not pushing correctly atm. I've tried every trick I could find online, but to no avail.

What I've done so far:

- Reset network connections. Did nothing.
- I've deleted and re-set up my email accounts in mail.app. Did nothing.
- All of the notification settings are correct, including push, and background update is on.
- Re-entered email account passwords, nothing.
- Both mail.app and gmail.app refuse to actually push mail and notify me unless I manually force a refresh. Even fetch doesn't work.

I'm not sure why this happened all of the sudden. I updated to 9.1 couple weeks ago, but the issue started a couple days ago. It's terrible for work, I'll get emails 2-3 hrs later when I randomly check.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you enable push? Or fetch?

Comment: @Rob - Push enabled for my gmail and non-gmail account. The gmail push can only be done via the gmail app, and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tested with a me.com or icloud.com account? I'm seeing no push issues from those. At least would narrow it down to being google, which seems to crop up with alarming regularity between iOS/OS X/gmail

Comment: Same issue. I have exhausted ALL the options. I'm on 9.2.1, btw, this issue still persists.

Comment: Have you tried to update your iPhone to the latest iOS? It might be an issue of that specific firmware running on your iPhone

Comment: I'm going to put this on hold since it doesn't include a specific mail service and push can often be tested explicitly as part of normal customer service between the end user and the mail provider. The existing answers have great tips, but since most people are on iOS 10 and have specific questions for specific providers of Mail - those questions would be better asked as more narrow and specific questions linking here if possible.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

Go to Settings >> Notifications.
Scroll down and find Mail section. Tap on it.
Select your mail app. For example, I am using Exchange.
Turn on “Show in Notification Center” and “Show on Lock Screen”.

Answer (score 0):

in iOS 9 you can customize Email Push setting from your iDevice setting app.

Here is the guide on [Enable Push Email on iPhone](http://www.howtoisolve.com/email-push-not-working-iphone-ipad-ios-9/), when you can't receive mail to your inbox automatically. Push option not available for other Mails (Gmail, Yahoo, iCloud, Exchange), But you can also set it just like push Mail.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please refrain from posting link-only answers.  Links can change and then users with a similar question can't access the answer.  See [answer] for tips on how to provide good answers.  - From Review -

Answer (score -3):

See here: [ios 9 notifications not working](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7229812?tstart=0)

Wait until the new iOS comes or update to iOS *9.2.1*,ok?